# В чем разница между такими объявлениями объекта класса?

Tags: c++, классы

Допустим, есть два класса – базовый и производный. Я могу объявить объект базового класса как `class A object1` и `A object2`

---

В чем разница между такими объявлениями ( не считая того, что это два разных объекта)?

```
    class A 
{
    //...
};

class B : public A
{
private:
  
    class A object1;

    A object2;

    //...
};
```

Comment: А зачем наследнику делать внутри ещё один экземпляр родителя? Он и так наследует все его члены. Обычно по архитектуре либо наследуют, либо содержат в себе объект.

Comment: @DmitryK, подозреваю, что просто для примера?

Comment: @Qwertiy для примера достаточно просто двух объявлений объекта. Зачем в классе-наследнике? Разницы-то никакой, что в наследнике, что просто в классе, что вообще без класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни в чём. Совместимость со структурами, а там - с кодом на Си.

Впрочем, в некоторых случаях использование ключевого слова `class` позволяет не объявлять данный класс выше в коде: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzknsbhYwUmhWgHCctRSSLRWqLXmyswrUchNzMzT0ATKOSloJQFF//8HAA)

```
class B { class A* a; };
int main() { B *b; }
```

Если здесь убрать слово `class`, то будет ошибка компиляции: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzknsbhYwUmhWsFRSyHRWqHWmiszr0QhNzEzT0MTKOqkoJUEFP3/HwA)

```
class B { A* a; };
int main() { B *b; }
```

> ```
> .code.tio.cpp:1:11: error: ‘A’ does not name a type
>  class B { A* a; };
>            ^
> ```

Придётся его объявлять отдельно: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzknsbhYwdGaC8JwUqhWcNRSSLRWqLXmyswrUchNzMzT0ASKOiloJQFF//8HAA)

```
class A;
class B { A* a; };
int main() { B *b; }
```

Comment: А может `class A object1` даёт сразу предварительное определение?

Comment: @maestro, не понял. Можно пример?

Comment: @Qweertiy, если написать `class C *obj`, то этот код скомпилируется, даже если определение класса `C` не содержится в данной единице трансляции.

Comment: @maestro, а если без `class`? Вот: [`class A;
class B { A* a; };
int main() { B *b; }`](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzknsbhYwdGaC8JwUqhWcNRSSLRWqLXmyswrUchNzMzT0ASKOiloJQFF//8HAA)

Comment: @maestro, а, понял: [`class B { A* a; };
int main() { B *b; }`](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzknsbhYwUmhWsFRSyHRWqHWmiszr0QhNzEzT0MTKOqkoJUEFP3/HwA) - не компилируется, а [`class B { class A* a; };
int main() { B *b; }`](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzknsbhYwUmhWgHCctRSSLRWqLXmyswrUchNzMzT0ATKOSloJQFF//8HAA) - компилируется.

Comment: @maestro, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @maestro, кстати, в случае `class A smth;` объявление-то будет, но совершенно бесполезное, потому что получится ошибка про incomplete type.

Comment: получается просто запись `class A * ap ;` делает два действия. Предварительно объявляет тип и указатель : `class A * ap ;` == `class A ; A * ap;` ?